# Annoying sign in geometric interpretation of curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, conventions, curvature

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AC3TMizGpB8&t=1203s) video Susskind gives a heuristic derivation of the curvature formula which I summarize as follows:

[image]

In a coordinate system, start with a vector $v_A$ at the origin, and extend it to a parallel vector field along the bottom side of the square (side length $\varepsilon$); let $v_B$ be the value at the bottom right corner. Then extend $v_B$ to a parallel vector field along the right side, obtaining $v_C$, which you similarly extend in parallel fashion along the top side to obtain $v_D$. Finally, you extend $v_D$ again parallel along the left side to obtain $v'_A$.

Now

$$ v_A - v'_A = [(v_C - v_D) - (v_B - v_A)] - [(v_C - v_B) - (v_D - v'_A)] $$

Note $v_C - v_D$ is ($\varepsilon$ times) a covariant derivative of $v$ (to first order) along the $\mu$ direction, and so is $v_B - v_A$. So reasonably we may write (to second order)

$$[(v_C - v_D) - (v_B - v_A)] = \varepsilon^2 \nabla_\nu \nabla_\mu v $$

since we took the difference of $\mu$ covariant derivatives, in the $\nu$ direction. The other term goes mutatis mutandis so that you end up finding (and this is indeed the result Susskind writes down)

$$v_A - v'_A = \varepsilon^2 [\nabla_\nu, \nabla_\mu] v$$

The only problem is I expected to have $[\nabla_\mu, \nabla_\nu]$ in the formula and not the other way around. That is how it's stated in Baez & Muniain's Gauge Fields, Knots and Gravity (p. 247), and also matches the formula obtained in Peskin & Schroeder (p. 484). It's a minor detail but I cannot figure out where this difference in sign could be coming from, and I'd really like to get this right.

Comment: Are you sure the sources where the sign is flipped are not looking at $v'_A - v_A$ instead? I would find it more natural to take the *final* $v'_A$ and subtract the initial $v_A$, at least.

Comment: Yes, I'm fairly sure. That's why the holonomy has the formula $1 - \varepsilon ^2 F_{\mu \nu}$ - Susskind's argument would give $1 + \varepsilon^2 F_{\mu \nu}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be that is just a matter of convention of the definition of the curvature? See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342288/conventions-for-riemann-curvature-tensor

(I would post this as a comment but don't have enough reputation)

EDIT: Let me give more details. The Riemann curvature tensor can be defined as:
$R(X,Y)Z=[\nabla_X,\nabla_Y]Z-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z $.
However, it can also be defined with a global opposite sign in front. It may be the case that Susskind is using the opposite convention as yours.

EDIT#2: now addressing the original question which I misinterpreted at first. I think the problem is not properly tracking second order contributions. First let me say that the RHS of the first equation could be misleading, since you cannot add vectors at different points. Of course we can understand that expression infinitesimally, with all vectors at the original point. Having said this, let me clarify that $v_C-v_D=\epsilon \nabla_\mu v_C$ is only valid up to first order, but since you are looking for a second order result, the correct way is to write
$$v_C-v_D=\epsilon \nabla_\mu v_C -\frac{\epsilon^2}{2} \nabla_\mu\nabla_\mu v_C$$
Then, $v_C$ needs to be written similarly in terms of $v_B$, and $v_B$ in terms of $v_A$  (always up to second order in $\epsilon$). Once this is done,  you get
$$v_A-v'_A=\epsilon^2 [\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\nu]v_A $$

Comment: It's not a matter of definition though. The question is: given that $v'_A$ is obtained from $v_A$ by parallel transport along the counter-clockwise square, what is the correct formula (up to second order) for $v_A - v'_A$? It's either $\varepsilon^2 [\nabla_\mu, \nabla_\nu] v$ or the other way around, and this is a concrete unambiguous question so the answer cannot boil down to conventions.

Comment: @Pedro the sign depends on whether you move clockwise or counterclockwise along the path. I think that in this sense it is a matter of definition

Comment: @Prallax "sign depends on whether you move clockwise or counterclockwise", that is true. But Pedro has already specified he's traversing the loop counterclockwise, so the signs are fixed, and so the question of whether it should be $\epsilon^2[\nabla_{\mu},\nabla_{\nu}]$ or the other way around is not a matter of convention anymore.

Comment: @Pedro, Ok. I thought your question was to relate the commutator you obtained to the curvature . I misinterpreted it, I'm  sorry. I will edit once again my answer in a while, to address your question on the order of commutators.

Comment: @AlanGarbarz Thank you, I believe I've worked it out (posted below). It seems that Susskind's argument is just wrong, though it gets tantalizingly close to the right answer by a much shorter route.

Comment: @Pedro, glad to help. Hope everyone is happy now...

Answer (score 3):

I believe I managed to do it following the lines indicated by Alan Garbarz. Let me write it here as it may be of interest.

Instead of following Susskind's argument (which I'm starting to suspect is just wrong), we do one transport at a time, *keeping only terms up to quadratic* in $\varepsilon$. We start with

$$v_B = v_A + \varepsilon \nabla_\mu v_A + \frac{\varepsilon^2}{2} \nabla^2_\mu v_A$$

Then

\begin{equation*} \begin{split}
 v_C & = v_B + \varepsilon \nabla_\nu v_B + \frac{\varepsilon^2}{2} \nabla^2_\nu v_B \\ & = \left( v_A + \varepsilon \nabla_\mu v_A + \frac{\varepsilon^2}{2} \nabla^2_\mu v_A \right) + \varepsilon \nabla_\nu v_A + \varepsilon^2 \nabla_\nu \nabla_\mu v_A + \frac{\varepsilon^2}{2} \nabla^2_\nu v_A
\end{split} \end{equation*}

This time we'll see some much needed cancellation (the minus sign is since $D$ is in the negative $\mu$ direction from $C$):

\begin{equation*} \begin{split}
v_D & = v_C - \varepsilon \nabla_\mu v_C + \frac{\varepsilon^2}{2} \nabla^2_\mu v_C \\
& = \left( v_A + \varepsilon \nabla_\mu v_A + \varepsilon \nabla_\nu v_A + \frac{\varepsilon^2}{2} \nabla^2_\mu v_A + \frac{\varepsilon^2}{2} \nabla^2_\nu v_A  + \varepsilon^2 \nabla_\nu \nabla_\mu v_A  \right) \\
& - \varepsilon \nabla_\mu v_A - \varepsilon^2 \nabla^2_\mu v_A - \varepsilon^2 \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu v_A + \frac{\varepsilon^2}{2} \nabla^2_\mu v_A \\
& = v_A + \varepsilon \nabla_\nu v_A + \frac{\varepsilon^2}{2} \nabla^2_\nu v_A + \varepsilon^2 [\nabla_\nu, \nabla_\mu]v_A
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Finally, we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
v'_A & = v_D - \varepsilon \nabla_\nu v_D + \frac{\varepsilon^2}{2} \nabla^2_\nu v_D \\
& = \left(v_A + \varepsilon \nabla_\nu v_A + \frac{\varepsilon^2}{2} \nabla^2_\nu v_A + \varepsilon^2 [\nabla_\nu, \nabla_\mu] v_A  \right) \\
& - \varepsilon \nabla_\nu v_A - \varepsilon^2 \nabla^2_\nu v_A + \frac{\varepsilon^2}{2} \nabla^2_\nu v_A \\
& = v_A + \varepsilon^2 [\nabla_\nu, \nabla_\mu]v_A
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Thus, at last,

$$ v_A - v'_A = - \varepsilon^2 [\nabla_\nu, \nabla_\mu]v_A = \varepsilon^2 [\nabla_\mu, \nabla_\nu]v_A $$

Comment: This reminds me very much of a [Taylor expansion question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3760642/568204) regarding a discrepancy in the sign arising from not keeping enough terms :)